# What the most efficient way of monitoring changes to data on an ASP.Net form?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net form and I want to send an email when the user changes their data. The email should only include data that has changed, and there are about 15 data fields total.

I don't want to use an ORM since I am updating a website that a 3rd party built for us, and all their data access calls go through a custom library of theirs.

The only ways to do this I can think of is

- Make another database call to get old values and compare the form values one-by-one. If they're different, append to the email.
- Store original data somewhere when it's first loaded (hidden field, session, etc), and once again compare the data one field at a time and append the differences to an email
- Have someone on SO tell me there's an easier and/or simpler way that I haven't thought of

Comment: Is it only the asp pages that you have - or do you have access to the data classes used on them? Do they implement INotifyProperty changed?

Comment: @ChrisBD The web site if pretty basic and doesn't follow any particular design pattern. Data is pulled into an `Object` or `DataSet` and manually applied to whatever controls need the data. For example, `txtFirstName = myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)("FirstName")`. It's not my preferred method of doing stuff, but I didn't want to have to rewrite the entire site so am going with what they have setup already.

Comment: @Rachel - Do you want the email to contain the original and new values or do you just need to know that a field *has* changed?

Comment: @M.Babcock Original and New values, and the field name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the text boxes will have a `TextChanged` event, you can have them mark themselves as modified.  ComboBox's will have a `SelectedIndexChanged` event, and so on.

Edit: All changed events can check their initial values (even on reverted changes) and either mark themselves as still modified or on a revert, as un-modified.

Comment: Unless changes that were reverted should be excluded from the list, in which case you're still looking at persisting initial values from post to post.

Comment: So you're suggesting hook up a `TextChanged` event to each TextBox, and in that event have the TextBox set some kind of flag on itself to say it was modified? That still doesn't help me much because I need the original values as well as the changed values, and it seems like it would only cause a huge mess. The email should only fire at the end when the user clicks Save, not when any field gets changed.

Comment: Yes, but you are not checking every value for changes, only those that have their changed event fired.

Comment: I feel this would complicate things as there are other PostBacks on the page, so I think I'd have to store the changed data in the Session between PostBacks. Also, I don't see anything to get the original value from a TextBox after a TextChanged event, so I think I have to store this myself. Since I would ideally like to not submit non-changed data when a user changes it and reverts back to the original value, I would also have to manage deleting data that has been reverted to its original value. It just seems like a lot of micro-managing for something without a lot of benefits

Comment: @ChuckSavage You know what, I take it back. I gave this a try and after getting it working, it actually is a simpler solution to the problem of only tracking changed data. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions that may / may not be useful:

- Trigger on the database table and the trigger compares the old (using the DELETED table) and updated (using the INSERTED table) and then sends an email. This may or may not be viable and I am not a big advocate of triggers.
- Like you have already said you could make another database call, which would be my reccommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said I think that the only way forward is to create a duplicate dataset on the form to store the old data and run a comparison at the point where you want to produce the email.

You can use `Dataset.Copy` to copy structure and data.

However, now that I think about it there's always the `Datset.GetChanges()` method and the `Dataset.AcceptChanges()` along with `DataSet.HasChanges()`

Example code from this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ey25we.aspx):

```
if(dataSet.HasChanges(DataRowState.Modified | 
        DataRowState.Added)&& dataSet.HasErrors)
    {
        // Use GetChanges to extract subset.
        changesDataSet = dataSet.GetChanges(
            DataRowState.Modified|DataRowState.Added);
        PrintValues(changesDataSet, "Subset values");

        // Insert code to reconcile errors. In this case, reject changes.
        foreach(DataTable changesTable in changesDataSet.Tables)
        {
            if (changesTable.HasErrors)
            {
                foreach(DataRow changesRow in changesTable.Rows)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(changesRow["Item"]);
                    if((int)changesRow["Item",DataRowVersion.Current ]> 100)
                    {
                        changesRow.RejectChanges();
                        changesRow.ClearErrors();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Add a column to the changesDataSet.
        changesDataSet.Tables["Items"].Columns.Add(
            new DataColumn("newColumn"));
        PrintValues(changesDataSet, "Reconciled subset values");
        // Merge changes back to first DataSet.
        dataSet.Merge(changesDataSet, false, 
            System.Data.MissingSchemaAction.Add);
    }
    PrintValues(dataSet, "Merged Values");
```